# Azure SQL Server Geo-replication Resource

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In my Azure SQL DB, I have Geo-reduntant backup storage enabled. According to documentatio this will [replicate the DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?tabs=single-database#backup-storage-redundancy) in the DB's [paired region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/best-practices-availability-paired-regions#what-are-paired-regions). However, I did not have to configure a new server instance, nor do I see any resources in my Portal that would indicate this backup actually exists.

I know the backup DB is not read/write accessible until a fail-over, but should I still be able to at least see the DB resource in the paired region? Under Replicas for my DB, the list is empty. I read somewhere (but can't remember which documentation) that a failover can be triggered manually or by Microsoft. In that instance wouldn't I need to have my app configured with a secondary connection string pointing at the backup? How would I get that connection string?

Also, if I got to create a new DB, and select Backup for "Use existing data", I don't have an option for the geo-replicated DB from my primary DB. So I guess I'm having a hard time seeing what the Geo-redundant option under "Compute + storage" even does.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Appears like what you are trying to configure is backup type which is [backup storage redundancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?tabs=single-database#configure-backup-storage-redundancy)  and not  [Geo Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-overview) . For Geo redundant backups you can [Geo Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/recovery-using-backups#geo-restore) . If you want GeoDR or [Failover groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auto-failover-group-overview?tabs=azure-powershell) that is configured differently

Comment: What I'm trying to do is backup my data in a different Azure region. I ended up manually creating the replica under the Replicas blade, which gave me the what I was looking for: a sync'd DB in a different region that we can use to restore data should the primary data center have a catastrophic failure. However, based on my research, the "Geo-redundant backup storage" seems like that setting should have been doing the DB back up  in Azure's paired region. So it's just unclear to me what selecting that option (as my screenshot shows) actually does.